# tomcat 8.5 clustering issue on 2 ubuntu vms - skipping state transfer. No members active in cluster group

Tags: azure, tomcat, tomcat8, tomcat8.5, session-replication

I am trying to create a tomcat cluster with 2 ubuntu machines.
Tomcat starts successfully on both vms. However, the war file is not copied on to node2. Error says: skipping state transfer. No members active in cluster group. Please let me know if anything is wrong in config.xml
I am using tomcat 8.5 on both vms.

Following is the content of `server.xml` on node1:

```xml
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="test01">
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
<Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"
                 channelSendOptions="8">

          <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager"
                   expireSessionsOnShutdown="false"
                   notifyListenersOnReplication="true"/>

          <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">
            <Membership className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService"
                        address="228.0.0.4"
                        port="45564"
                        frequency="500"
                        dropTime="3000"/>
            <Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver"
                      address="auto"
                      port="4000"
                      autoBind="100"
                      selectorTimeout="5000"
                      maxThreads="6"/>

            <Sender className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter">
              <Transport className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.PooledParallelSender"/>
            </Sender>
            <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector"/>
            <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.MessageDispatchInterceptor"/>
          </Channel>

          <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve"
                 filter=""/>
          <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve"/>

          <Deployer className="org.apache.catalina.ha.deploy.FarmWarDeployer"
                    tempDir="/tmp/war-temp/"
                    deployDir="/tmp/war-deploy/"
                    watchDir="/tmp/war-listen/"
                    watchEnabled="false"/>

          <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener"/>
        </Cluster>
</Host>
</Engine>
```

Following is the content of `server.xml` on node 2:

```xml
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="test02">
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
<Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"
                 channelSendOptions="8">

          <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager"
                   expireSessionsOnShutdown="false"
                   notifyListenersOnReplication="true"/>

          <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">
            <Membership className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService"
                        address="228.0.0.4"
                        port="45564"
                        frequency="500"
                        dropTime="3000"/>
            <Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver"
                      address="auto"
                      port="4000"
                      autoBind="100"
                      selectorTimeout="5000"
                      maxThreads="6"/>

            <Sender className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter">
              <Transport className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.PooledParallelSender"/>
            </Sender>
            <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector"/>
            <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.MessageDispatchInterceptor"/>
          </Channel>

          <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve"
                 filter=""/>
          <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve"/>

          <Deployer className="org.apache.catalina.ha.deploy.FarmWarDeployer"
                    tempDir="/tmp/war-temp/"
                    deployDir="/tmp/war-deploy/"
                    watchDir="/tmp/war-listen/"
                    watchEnabled="false"/>

          <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener"/>
        </Cluster>
</Host>
</Engine>
```

Log from `catalina.out` node1 is as follows:

```
26-May-2021 13:01:50.682 INFO [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster.startInternal Cluster is about to start
26-May-2021 13:01:50.686 INFO [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReceiverBase.bind Receiver Server Socket bound to:/10.1.0.7:4000
26-May-2021 13:01:50.696 INFO [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl.setupSocket Setting cluster mcast soTimeout to 500
26-May-2021 13:01:50.701 INFO [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl.waitForMembers Sleeping for 1000 milliseconds to establish cluster membership, start level:4
26-May-2021 13:01:51.701 INFO [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl.waitForMembers Done sleeping, membership established, start level:4
26-May-2021 13:01:51.702 INFO [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl.waitForMembers Sleeping for 1000 milliseconds to establish cluster membership, start level:8
26-May-2021 13:01:52.703 INFO [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl.waitForMembers Done sleeping, membership established, start level:8
26-May-2021 13:01:52.704 INFO [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.ha.deploy.FarmWarDeployer.start Cluster FarmWarDeployer started.
26-May-2021 13:01:52.739 INFO [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve.startInternal JvmRouteBinderValve started
26-May-2021 13:01:52.763 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /opt/tomcat/webapps/test.war
26-May-2021 13:02:22.826 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager.startInternal Register manager /test to cluster element Host with name localhost
26-May-2021 13:02:22.827 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager.startInternal Starting clustering manager at /test
26-May-2021 13:02:22.827 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager.getAllClusterSessions Manager [/test]: skipping state transfer. No members active in cluster group.
```

Logs from `catalina.out` node2 is as follows:

```
26-May-2021 13:00:59.544 INFO [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster.startInternal Cluster is about to start
26-May-2021 13:00:59.617 INFO [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReceiverBase.bind Receiver Server Socket bound to:/10.2.0.5:4000
26-May-2021 13:00:59.633 INFO [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl.setupSocket Setting cluster mcast soTimeout to 500
26-May-2021 13:00:59.636 INFO [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl.waitForMembers Sleeping for 1000 milliseconds to establish cluster membership, start level:4
26-May-2021 13:01:00.636 INFO [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl.waitForMembers Done sleeping, membership established, start level:4
26-May-2021 13:01:00.638 INFO [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl.waitForMembers Sleeping for 1000 milliseconds to establish cluster membership, start level:8
26-May-2021 13:01:01.639 INFO [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl.waitForMembers Done sleeping, membership established, start level:8
26-May-2021 13:01:01.640 INFO [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.ha.deploy.FarmWarDeployer.start Cluster FarmWarDeployer started.
26-May-2021 13:01:01.669 INFO [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve.startInternal JvmRouteBinderValve started
```

Comment: What kind of virtual machines are you using? They might be in separate multicast domains, hence, they never see each other.

Comment: the vms are having ubuntu 18.04 OS and they are on the same virtual network on azure. How do i check whether they are in seperate multicast domains?